# Unix Add double quotes in string

Tags: unix

I need to declare a string like below

ext = "EXT

But I am not able to achieve it.
I tried below code and it is not worked

ext = '"EXT'

above code giving null only

Please help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: Assuming you are using `bash` or some other `sh` derivative, an assignment is a single word, meaning no spaces around the `=`.

Comment: Did you overlook the "command not found" error when you tried to execute the command `ext`?

Comment: Thanks for your help. It's working now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have given extra space before and after the `=`
The second way which you tried and suggested in other answers will work:

`ext='"EXT'`

Answer (score 0):

You may try using escape character "" and try something like this :

```
ext="\"EXT"
```

Comment: The quoting in the OP's second example is fine; it's the spaces around the `=` that caused the problem.

Answer (score 0):

ext='"EXT' should work (at least in bash).

You have space between ext and equal sign. That could be a problem.